# How to "group" a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

how does one group a polynomial when the coefficients can't be grouped?
By grouping I mean finding two numbers that when multiplied together make the squared coefficient and added together make the other. For example, $6w^2-11w-10$ can be grouped as $6w^2 + 4w - 15w - 10$. But in this problem I have, the polynomial $-8w^2-18w-9$, no number can be grouped into $-8$ and $-18$. In other words, no two numbers added together make $-18$ and multiply to $-8$. I can solve the polynomial but the question specifically asks for the grouping first. How do I group an un-groupable polynomial?

Comment: Can you tell us what your goal is in "grouping" it that way? It seems similar to completing the square but is not quite so.

Answer (score 1):

You may try $$8w^2+18w+9 = $$

$$8w^2+12w+6w+9 =$$

$$ 4w(2w+3)+3(2w+3)=$$

$$(4w+3)(2w+3)$$